# kindly check my code how can i create separate category for my new custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

```
                    function create_post_type_opportunities() {
                        register_post_type( 'opportunities',
                        // CPT Options
                        array(
                          'labels' => array(
                           'name' => __( 'Opportunities'),
                           'singular_name' => __( 'Opportunities')                             
                          ),
                          'public' => true,
                          'has_archive' => false,
                          'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'opportunities'),
                          'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor','icon' ),               
                          )); }
                        // Hooking up our function to theme setup
                        add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_opportunities');
                        /* Custom Post Type for our Add opportunities*/
```

here is my code kindly check my code  how can i create separate category for my new custom post type

Answer (score 0):

```
    function custom_post_type() {
// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Movies', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Movie', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );
     
// Set other options for Custom Post Type 
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Movie news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
     


        // This is where we add taxonomies to our CPT
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
    );
 


    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'movies', $args );
 
}

 
 
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );

To display your custom post types on the same category page as your default posts, you need to add this code into your theme’s functions.php or a site-specific plugin.

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if( is_category() ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'post', 'movies'); // don't forget nav_menu_item `enter code here`to allow menus to work!
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```